# Inequality of the Jacobian implies inequality of norm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $J_{F}$ denoted the Jacobian of $F$.  Similarly, let $G: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $J_{G}$ be the Jacobian of $G$. If

$h^{T}(J_{F}(x))^{T}(J_F(x))h \leq h^{T}(J_{G}(x))^{T}(J_G(x))h$, $\quad\forall x,h \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Then does it imply that $||F(x)-F(y)||_{2} \leq ||G(x)-G(y)||_{2}$, $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$?

If not, is it true if $F$ and $G$ are monotone operators, i.e., $(F(x)-F(y))^{T}(x-y)\geq 0$ or alternatively $h^{T}J_F(x)h \geq 0$, $\forall x,h \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?

---

I have tried using the fact that $\int_{0}^{1}J_{F}(y + t(x-y))(x-y)dt = F(x)-F(y)$ and $J_{F}(x)h = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{F(x+th) - F(x)}{t}$ but I don't know how to remove the limit or integral to show $||F(x)-F(y)||_{2} \leq ||G(x)-G(y)||_{2}$.